# OneDrive app does not launch on macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: macos, terminal, applications, onedrive

I would like to use the OneDrive app on macOS Catalina 10.15.7. I have tried double-clicking, left-clicking and selecting "Open", and even tried launching the app from the terminal. However, it simply refuses to launch.

I tried monitoring the system with Activity Monitor as I tried to launch the application. Sometimes it momentarily appears as using CPU and energy resources, before simply vanishing. Other times it does not even show up in Activity Monitor. The installed version is 14.5.2 which at the time of writing, is the current version on the App Store.

I have tried resetting the app following [these instructions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reset-onedrive-34701e00-bf7b-42db-b960-84905399050c#:%7E:text=To%20reset%20OneDrive%20on%20a%20Mac&text=Right%2Dclick%20OneDrive%20and%20select,and%20finish%20the%20setup%20process.), but no improvements are noticed. Several attempts at uninstalling and re-installing the application does not help it run on my Mac.

What else can I check or try to get it to start?

Comment: I've removed the crash tag and simplified the question - are you seeing any crash log or specific thing that makes you think it starts and aborts?

Comment: What version of OneDrive? MS states though they haven't yet blocked it on 10.14 or 10.15 they only actually support macOS 11 & above.

Comment: @bmike As mentioned in the question, sometimes it momentarily shows up in Activity Monitor, but it then disappears shortly after trying to launch

Comment: That would align with the program starting, doing some checks and then intentionally quitting - good extra detail that would help if you wanted to edit that into the question - along with the specific version of OneDrive you chose to install. After installing are you letting Microsoft update get a newer version or do you try to stick with the version you installed (for reasons).

Comment: @bmike The first part is already in the question. I will add the specific version: 14.5.2 which is the one currently found on Apple's App Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, this issue is well known [Microsoft's community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/onedrive-will-not-run-macos-catalina-10157/ddb9a0d0-09ac-4ff6-bfd6-0b1629c391ab). Following some positive feedback in that thread, I have installed version [23.054.0313.0003](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=823060) which appears to be the last version that properly runs under Catalina 10.15.7.

I have experienced one crash on the first launch during set up. I launched it again and was able to finish the set up without issues. So far it keeps working in my system.